# Array not displaying data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an object that I map into an empty array of string. So I can populate the string data, but the weird thing is, when I try to paste the data inside an array of objects it shows the data. In the example below I show you what I mean.

```
// My view Controller
    var filterClasses = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8470588235, green: 0.8470588235, blue: 0.8470588235, alpha: 0.66)

        populateClasses()

        // The array not show up in my tableViewCell
        chooseClass.dropView.options = filterClasses

        // The array show up in my tableViewCell
        // This data is from filter class
        chooseClass.dropView.options = ["8-1", "8-10", "8-2", "8-3", "8-4", "8-5", "8-6", "8-7"]
    }

    private func populateClasses() {
        AddScheduleServices.shared.getListClass { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let classes):
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.filterClasses = classes.compactMap { $0.name }
                print(self.filterClasses)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // This is a custom view from "chooseClass.dropView.options"
    class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView           = UITableView()
    var options             = [String]()

    var completion: ((String) -> Void)?
    var isHideSchedule      = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func configure() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.9764705882, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate      = self
        tableView.dataSource    = self

        tableView.anchor(top: topAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        completion?(options[indexPath.row])

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I don't what went wrong with my array chooseClass.dropView.options. Can you tell me why my array is not displayed in my tableview?

Comment: seems option array always empty. because no data append to it anywhere in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is async I suppose `AddScheduleServices.shared.getListClass`, so you have to reload the table after fetching data.

**1. update `options` on success:**

```swift
private func populateClasses() {
       //...
        case .success(let classes):
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.filterClasses = classes.compactMap { $0.name }
            self.chooseClass.dropView.options = self.filterClasses // <-- here
        //...
        }
}
```

**2. reload table view when set new options:**

```swift
class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //...
    var options  = [String]() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: hey thank you @AndrewBogaevskyi it might be not work because I place the chooseClass.dropView.options in viewDidLoad. and not reloading data in tableView like you did.